# Prestashop - Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'self::TYPE_STRING'

Tags: admin, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am developing a module in prestashop 1.6, i extend AdminController class, every thing is nice.but when i want to display the form that permit to add new instance an error message is displayed :

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'self::TYPE_STRING' in C:\xampp\htdocs\prestashop\classes\controller\AdminController.php on line 1418
```

Answer (score 0):

`self::TYPE_STRING` is a constant from `ObjectModel`, not `AdminController`.

I don't know why you'd want use it inside `AdminController`, but if really need to, change it to : `ObjectModel::TYPE_STRING`.

Keyword `self` referes to the current class you're in (in this it is `AdminController`)

Comment: i didn't use it in AdminController, i use it in my ObjectModel. but i define my model name in adminComtroller by this line :$this->className = 'SelStockProductModel';

Comment: Sorry, didn't look at the error more closely. Looks like some has modified `\classes\controller\AdminController.php` as Line 1418. Can you paste the code of what's there? Did you modify it yourself? Because PrestaShop doesn't come like this by default, it's definitely a silly error.

Comment: No, I didn't modify the AdminController. I downloaded new one and replaced it with mine, dispite that i get the same error.that  line contains this code : $this->object = new $this->className();

Comment: You should paste more code to your question. The current suspition is that you didn't extend 'ObjectModel' class

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can create the missing constant with code like this:

```
class Test {

     private const TYPE_STRING = 'string value';
     
     public function getString() {
           return self::TYPE_STRING;
     }
}
```